# While fitting a logistic regression ( glm) model I am getting "Error in glm.fit"

Tags: r, glm

I am fitting a logistic regression model with `glm()`.

The problem is with the last two variables: `change_per_call` and `change_per_min`.

My data structure is:

```
<pre>
   'data.frame':    66115 obs. of  54 variables:
         $ Customer_ID    : num  1030539 1025498 1053921 1005718 1046164 ...
         $ actvsubs       : num  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
         $ adjrev         : num  1017 1784 821 1398 404 ...
         $ adjmou         : num  5690 9367 5161 7294 1975 ...
         $ avgmou         : num  284 468 469 203 152 ...
         $ avgrev         : num  50.8 89.2 74.6 38.9 31.1 ...
         $ avgqty         : num  92 277.2 116.8 59.5 65.8 ...
         $ age1           : num  52 60 30 56 0 20 52 34 32 0 ...
         $ age2           : num  34 66 28 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ blck_dat_Mean  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ callwait_Mean  : num  0 4 0.667 0 0.333 ...
         $ callwait_Range : num  0 2 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 ...
         $ change_mou     : num  -97.5 129 339.8 86 -63.2 ...
         $ children       : num  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ comp_vce_Mean  : num  43.3 304.3 154.7 7 51 ...
         $ custcare_Mean  : num  0 0 1 0 0 ...
         $ datovr_Mean    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ da_Mean        : num  0.743 0 0.495 0 0 ...
         $ drop_blk_Mean  : num  5.667 26.333 6.333 0.333 3.333 ...
         $ drop_dat_Mean  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ drop_vce_Mean  : num  2 21 4.333 0.333 2 ...
         $ eqpdays        : num  633 178 97 748 427 474 279 332 362 885 ...
         $ forgntvl       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ income         : num  6 6 8 9 5.79 ...
         $ months         : num  21 22 12 38 14 16 9 23 12 30 ...
         $ mou_Mean       : num  166 590 695 76 125 ...
         $ ovrmou_Mean    : num  10 253 91 0 0 ...
         $ ovrrev_Mean    : num  3.5 88.6 27.3 0 0 ...
         $ retdays        : num  235 235 235 235 235 ...
         $ rev_Range      : num  14.99 75.95 110.19 0 0.54 ...
         $ roam_Mean      : num  0.292 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ totcalls       : num  1843 5586 1285 2181 865 ...
         $ totrev         : num  1049 1835 911 1449 464 ...
         $ wrkwoman       : num  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ asl_flag       : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ dwlltype       : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
         $ refurb_new     : num  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
         $ mtrcycle       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ truck          : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ hnd_price      : num  150 30 130 150 150 ...
         $ models         : num  1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
         $ numbcars       : num  2 1 1 2 1.57 ...
         $ churn          : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
         $ urban          : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
         $ city           : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ suburban       : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
         $ town           : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ married        : num  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
         $ married_A      : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ married_B      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
         $ married_S      : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
         $ webcap         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
         <strong>$ change_per_call: num  0.569 0.328 0.709 0.664 0.537 ...
         $ change_per_min : num  0.179 0.19 0.159 0.192 0.205 ...</strong>
</pre>
```

When I fit the model without the `change_per_call` and `change_per_min` variables, I get the following output:

```
 model5 <- glm(formula =churn~ actvsubs+ adjrev+ 
                  #adjmou+ 
                  avgmou+ 
                  #avgrev+
                  #avgqty+
                  age1+
                  #age2+
                  #blck_dat_Mean+
                  #callwait_Mean+ 
                  #callwait_Range+ 
                  change_mou+ children+comp_vce_Mean+custcare_Mean+
                  #datovr_Mean+
                  #da_Mean+ 
                  #drop_blk_Mean+
                  #drop_dat_Mean+
                  drop_vce_Mean+eqpdays+
                  #forgntvl+
                  #income+
                  months+mou_Mean+
                  #ovrmou_Mean+
                  ovrrev_Mean+
                  retdays+rev_Range+roam_Mean+
                  #totcalls+
                  #totrev+
                  wrkwoman+asl_flag+dwlltype+refurb_new+
                  #mtrcycle+truck+
                  hnd_price+models
                #+numbcars
                ,data = train[,-1], family = "binomial")

    summary(model5)

Call:
glm(formula = churn ~ actvsubs + adjrev + avgmou + age1 + change_mou + 
    children + comp_vce_Mean + custcare_Mean + drop_vce_Mean + 
    eqpdays + months + mou_Mean + ovrrev_Mean + retdays + rev_Range + 
    roam_Mean + wrkwoman + asl_flag + dwlltype + refurb_new + 
    hnd_price + models, family = "binomial", data = train[, -1])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3444  -0.7723  -0.6684  -0.4529   2.6948  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.420e-01  9.426e-02  -5.750 8.91e-09 ***
actvsubs       3.840e-02  1.769e-02   2.170 0.029970 *  
adjrev        -7.662e-05  2.339e-05  -3.276 0.001053 ** 
avgmou         7.974e-04  6.461e-05  12.341  < 2e-16 ***
age1          -6.242e-03  5.647e-04 -11.053  < 2e-16 ***
change_mou    -1.625e-04  4.536e-05  -3.583 0.000339 ***
children       7.449e-02  2.816e-02   2.645 0.008171 ** 
comp_vce_Mean -8.242e-04  1.943e-04  -4.242 2.21e-05 ***
custcare_Mean -7.873e-03  3.122e-03  -2.522 0.011669 *  
drop_vce_Mean  9.510e-03  1.618e-03   5.878 4.14e-09 ***
eqpdays        1.068e-03  7.618e-05  14.017  < 2e-16 ***
months        -1.189e-02  2.308e-03  -5.153 2.57e-07 ***
mou_Mean      -7.885e-04  6.308e-05 -12.502  < 2e-16 ***
ovrrev_Mean    5.766e-03  6.177e-04   9.335  < 2e-16 ***
retdays       -1.884e-03  3.047e-04  -6.184 6.24e-10 ***
rev_Range      3.309e-04  2.382e-04   1.389 0.164751    
roam_Mean      3.713e-03  1.160e-03   3.201 0.001370 ** 
wrkwoman      -5.017e-02  3.523e-02  -1.424 0.154425    
asl_flag      -4.570e-01  3.801e-02 -12.024  < 2e-16 ***
dwlltype       7.346e-02  2.841e-02   2.586 0.009715 ** 
refurb_new    -1.958e-01  3.632e-02  -5.390 7.03e-08 ***
hnd_price     -1.519e-03  2.359e-04  -6.436 1.23e-10 ***
models         1.059e-01  2.036e-02   5.201 1.98e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 50785  on 46279  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 49410  on 46257  degrees of freedom
AIC: 49456
```

If I add the variables `change_per_call` and `change_per_min`, I get an error message:

```
model6 <- glm(formula =churn~ actvsubs+ adjrev+ 
              #adjmou+ 
              avgmou+ 
              #avgrev+
              #avgqty+
              age1+
              #age2+
              #blck_dat_Mean+
              #callwait_Mean+ 
              #callwait_Range+ 
              change_mou+ children+comp_vce_Mean+custcare_Mean+
              #datovr_Mean+
              #da_Mean+ 
              #drop_blk_Mean+
              #drop_dat_Mean+
              drop_vce_Mean+eqpdays+
              #forgntvl+
              #income+
              months+mou_Mean+
              #ovrmou_Mean+
              ovrrev_Mean+
              retdays+rev_Range+roam_Mean+
              #totcalls+
              #totrev+
              wrkwoman+asl_flag+dwlltype+refurb_new+
              #mtrcycle+truck+
              hnd_price+models
            #+numbcars
            +change_per_call+ change_per_min,data = train[,-1], 
            family = "binomial")
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

Note: the variablea `change_per_call` `change_per_min`  are both numeric; they don't contain any zero values.

How can I overcome this type of error?

After removing the infinite value of the following two variables

**`change_per_call` and `change_per_min`**  I got following summary result

```
 summary(tele6$change_per_call)
        Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
      0.0353   0.2914   0.4377   0.8324   0.7084 366.9400 
    > 
    > summary(tele6$change_per_min)
        Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
      0.0100   0.0974   0.1409   0.3300   0.2276 622.3750 
    >
```

@Ben Bolker, Now I am not having "0", no "infinite" But still showing the **Error in glm.fit**

Comment: did you check for `NAs` in those two variables?

Comment: `apply(is.na(tele6), 2, sum)`

Comment: `glm` should automatically remove rows with missing values, so I don't think `NA` values would be an issue. Do either of the two variables have at least one observation equal to `Inf` or `-Inf`.

Comment: what is the result of `options("na.omit")`? `summary(train[,c("change_per_call","change_per_min")])` ?

Comment: @eipi10, I think that's the best guess so far. I can replicate the error with a tiny data set containing `Inf` in the input. Also, it makes some sense that there would be an observation somewhere with 0 duration, so that a change-per-duration variable would end up as `Inf`.

Comment: @Ben, yes I found my max value for the above 2 variables is inf after doing > summary(tele6$change_per_min)
  
> summary(tele6$change_per_call)
   

>

Comment: so you should be able to write a solution for your own problem and post it ...

Comment: Yes, after removing the "infinite" value from those specific variable variables I am getting best model fit.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of your data is numeric, you may try to scale() the data and also by using lda() from the MASS package. 
LDA and Logistic mostly but not always give the same result.

I suppose you've already tried to see what is the range() for the two variables in question to check if they have unusually large or small values.

Comment: yes I found my max value for the above 2 variables is "infinite" after doing > summary(tele6$change_per_min) > summary(tele6$change_per_call)

Comment: Yes, after removing the "infinite" value from those specific variable variables I am getting best model fit.

Comment: please answer your own question - don't just leave the answer sitting in comments!